# Not getting correct sorted array with a counting sort

Tags: c++, sorting, counting-sort

I am working on the Counting Sort Algorithm currently. I have set up two temporary arrays `C` and `B`. `C` is to count the number of times a  number in the original array appears. It then uses the elements in `C` to place the elements in `A` (original array) into the correct location in `B`. I have my `countingSort` function print out `C` after each loop to ensure that it has the correct values in it (which it does, I'm testing it with a small sample size). The problem occurs when I go to insert the elements of `A` into `B` with the help of `C`.

Here is my function for `countingSort`:

Note: I pass an array of 10 integers `2 0 3 2 5 4 3 6 10` to the function,the temporary array `B`, the `maximum` value (so I know what size to make `C`) and the size of array `A`

```
void countingSort(int A[], int B[], int k, int size){
    int C[k + 1];
    cout << "K: " << k << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < k + 1; i++){
        C[i] = 0;
    }



    for(int i = 0; i < k + 1; i++){
        cout << C[i] << " ";
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        C[A[i]] = C[A[i]] + 1;
    }

    cout << endl;


    for(int i = 0; i < k + 1; i++){
        cout << C[i] << " ";
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < k + 1; i++){
        C[i] = C[i] + C[i - 1];
    }


    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < k + 1; i++){
        cout << C[i] << " ";
    }



    for(int i = size + 1; i > 0; i--){
        B[C[A[i]]] = A[i];
        C[A[i]] = C[A[i]] - 1;
    }


    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cout << B[i] << " ";
    }


}
```

As you can see I print out `C` after each loop, so after the first loop it should show that `C` is `0 0 0 0 0 0`, which it does print out correctly. After the next for loop it `C` should be `2 1 2 2 1 1 1`, which it also prints out correctly. Next it adds the elements of `C` up to get `2 3 5 7 8 9 10`, which is also printed out correctly. Now my issue arises here when I try to put the elements of `A` into `B`. It is supposed to print `0 0 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 6`, but it prints `0 0 0 1 0 2 3 3 4  5` instead.

I have tried playing around with my indexes on the last for loop, but just cant seem to figure out what is causing `B` to be incorrect. How could I fix this issue? My overall goal is to get the count sort to work for a randomly generated array of size `40` with numbers between 1 and 25.

Edit: Main Function where I call `countingSort`:

```
int sizeCount1 = 10;
int countOne[10] = {2, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3 ,6, 1, 0};

cout << "Counting Sort Version 1 (Pre Sort)" << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < sizeCount1; i++){
    cout << countOne[i] << " ";
}

cout << endl;


for(int i = 0; i < sizeCount1; i++){
    countTemp[i] = 0;
}



int max = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < sizeCount1; i++){
    if(countOne[i] > max){
        max = countOne[i];
    }
}

cout << "Max: " << max << endl;


countingSort(countOne, countTemp, max, sizeCount1);

cout << endl;

cout << "Counting Sort Version 1 (Post Sort)" << endl;


for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    cout << countTemp[i] << " ";
}

cout << endl << endl;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [MCVE].

Comment: `int C[k + 1];` is not legal C++. There are no VLAs. You may want to use std::vector instead.

Comment: I'm restricted from using vectors unfortunately

Comment: Restricted from using vectors but not restricted from using non-standard non-portable constructs? You are taking an interesting class (from the entomological perspective).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 1; i < k + 1; i++){
    C[i] = C[i] + C[i - 1];
}
```

Otherwise you are getting undefined behavior.

Also in the output array formation

```
for(int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--){
    B[C[A[i]]] = A[i];
    C[A[i]] = C[A[i]] - 1;
}
```

You got the algorithm right. Now just dry run a bit. That way you can find these kind of errors in your code.

<sub>As the OP used the `0-indexing`. I am using the same in my answer</sub>

<sub>In case you can't use vector ..allocate memory using `new`. Check the reference a bit for this.</sub>

<sub>Another thing is whenever you code counting sort always try to prove that you can hold the range in the auxiliary arrays. That helps.</sub>

#### Counting sort code:

```
void countingSort(int A[], int B[], int k, int size){
    int C[k + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < k + 1; i++){
        C[i] = 0;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        C[A[i]] = C[A[i]] + 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < k + 1; i++){
        C[i] = C[i] + C[i - 1];
    }
    for(int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--){
        B[C[A[i]]] = A[i];
        C[A[i]] = C[A[i]] - 1;
    }
}
```

#### main code

```
int sizeCount1 = 10;
int countOne[10] = {2, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3 ,6, 1, 0};

cout << "Counting Sort Version 1 (Pre Sort)" << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < sizeCount1; i++){
    countTemp[i] = 0;
}
int max = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < sizeCount1; i++){
    if(countOne[i] > max){
        max = countOne[i];
    }
}

cout << "Max: " << max << endl;


countingSort(countOne, countTemp, max, sizeCount1);
cout << "Counting Sort Version 1 (Post Sort)" << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    cout << countTemp[i] << " ";
}

cout << endl << endl;
```

Comment: So i changed that section and still got the same output, however I did change the last for loop to `for(int i = size; i >= 0; i++)` and I got `0 0 0  1 2 2 3 3 4 5` which is close but it has an extra 0 at the beginning and not the 6 at the end.

Comment: @zsloan112.: `i=size-1` You have iterated one extra time that's why geeting an extra 0. Make it frm `i=size-1` and `for(int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: As soon as I changed it to `i = size - 1` i got a segmentation fault

Comment: @zsloan112.: You should decrement `i`. Check `for(int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: That is what I have: `for(int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: @zsloan112.: Sitting here I can't debug your code. Just use the debugger or post the full code...There manybe othr reason why your code is failing...BTW as n.m. said you should use vector here ..VLA is not allowed.

Comment: I added my main function to the original post

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for all your help!